# Writing indexOf function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am new to JavaScript. I have created a indexof function in but it is not giving the correct output:
Question is:
/*
Implement a function called indexOf that accepts two parameters: a string and a character, and returns the first index of character in the string. 
*/

This is my code:

```
function indexOf(string, character) {
  let result = string;
  let i = 0;
  let output = 1;

  while (i < result.length) {
    if (result[i] === character) {
      output = output + indexOf[i];
    }
  }

  return output;
}
```

I want to know what i am doing wrong. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming from your question that the exercise is to only match the first occurrence of a character and not a substring (multiple characters in a row), then the most direct way to do it is the following:

```
const indexOf = (word, character) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] === character) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

If you also need to match substrings, leave a comment on this answer if you can't figure it out and I'll help you along.

Answer (score 3):

You are making things a little harder than you need to. If you want to do this without calling the built-in `indexOf()`, which I assume is the point of the exercise, you just need to `return` from the function as soon as your condition matches. The instructions say "return the first **index**" — that's the `i` in your loop.

If you make it through the loop without finding something it's traditional to return `-1`:

```js
function indexOf(string, character) {
    let i=0;
    while(i < string.length){
        if(string[i] == character){  // yes? just return the index i
            return i
        }
        i++                          // no? increase i and move on to next loop iteration
    }
    return -1;                       // made it through the loop and without returning. This means no match was found.
}
console.log(indexOf("Mark Was Here", "M"))
console.log(indexOf("Mark Was Here", "W"))
console.log(indexOf("Mark Was Here", "X"))
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() is a built in method for strings that tells you the index of a particular character in a word. Note that this will always return the index of the FIRST matching character.-

You can write something like:

```
function indexOf(string, character){
   return string.indexOf(character)
}
```

So if I were to use my function and pass in the two required arguments:

```
indexOf("woof", "o") //this would return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can be instead of indexOf(), the first param for the word u wants to search in and the second param for the string u want to search with.

```
function insteadIndexOF(mainWord,checkerWord){
  let one = ''
  let two = ''
  for(let i = 0 ; i < checkerWord.length ; i++){
    one += mainWord[i]
    two += checkerWord[i]
  }
  if(one === two ){
    return 0
  }
  return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ["I", "study", "JavaScript"];

function indexOf(str){
  for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    if (str === arr[i]) {
      return i
    }
  }
  return -1;

}
console.log(indexOf("JavaScript"))
```

Comment: This is almost the same code (except for array declaration and console output) as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77472166